# Unable to assign data returned from http Get to typescript object with same structure

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-httpclient, angular2-observables

I am calling a http Get service method from a component with the aim of mapping the response back to a Person object within my component for display on the front end.

my component:

```
export class DisplayPersonComponent implements OnInit {

  personId: number;
  person: Person;
  
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private service : PersonService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
       this.personId = params['person-id']});    
       
       this.getPerson(this.personId);
  }

  
    getPerson(id: number)
    {
        this.service.getPerson(id).subscribe((data: Person) => { console.log(data); 
          this.person = data
         });
    }
}
```

my service method:

```
getPerson(personId : number): Observable<Person> {

    let urlParams = new HttpParams().set("personId", personId.toString());

    return this.http.get<Person>(this.apiUrl, { params:  urlParams})
      .pipe(map((data: Person ) => { return data }),
        catchError(error => { return throwError(' Something went wrong! ');
        })
      );
  }
}
```

I can inspect the data object in the component when it returns and it looks like json ie
{ PersonID: 1, Name: 'Name'} etc
But this.Person is always undefined and there is no output/error to explain why.
It's also worth mentioning I use the same objects for a POST method and it works fine and maps perfectly from client to server without any specified mapping.

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit sleepy when I first wrote my answer, but there's been two edits since. Also, tag your question with [rxjs] too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `this.personId` is assigned asynchronously. So by the time `getPerson()` is called, it's still undefined.

Instead of nested subscriptions, you could use RxJS higher order mapping operator like `switchMap` to map from one observable to another.

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.route.params.pipe(
    switchMap(params => this.service.getPerson(params['person-id']))
  ).subscribe((data: Person) => {
    console.log(data);
    this.person = data;
  })
}
```

#### Option 2: `async` pipe

If you aren't using `this.person` in the controller, you could skip the subscription there and use `async` pipe in the template

Controller

```js
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

export class DisplayPersonComponent implements OnInit {
  person$: Observable<Person>; // <-- type `Observable`
  
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private service : PersonService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.person$ = this.route.params.pipe(
      switchMap(params => this.service.getPerson(params['person-id']))
    );
  }
}
```

Template

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="(person$ | async) as person">
  {{ person }}
  <some-comp [person]="person">...</some-comp>
</ng-container>
```

#### Update: `Cannot read property`

The error is thrown because the `person` variable is undefined until it's assigned a value inside the subscription. The second option using `async` should mitigate the issue. In any case, you could use safe navigation operator `?.` to check if a variable is defined before trying to access it's properties.

```html
<div>
  {{ person?.personId }}
  {{ person?.someProp }}
  {{ person?.someOtherProp }}
</div>
```

You could learn more about asynchronous data [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/6513921).

Comment: I tried this but am getting the error: 'Cannot read property 'personId' of undefined' from the html where I am calling person.PersonId

Comment: So with the above code do I need to modify my getPerson method in the service? It's already set to return a type Observable<Person> but is now returning the 'something went wrong' error

Comment: If it's returning the error, then something is wrong with the HTTP request. Please check if the back-end is working as expected and if the call is correct in the browser. Otherwise the method in the service looks fine to me.

Comment: Yes it's always returned the object as expected from the server. I will keep looking thank you - the component is now working where it wasn't before so I'm going to mark this as the answer as I have closed the gap in my knowledge with observables!

Answer (score 0):

Observables are `async`, by the moment you're evaluating `person`, the method inside subscribe that is called when the observable completes hasn't been called yet.

I don't know where you're using the `person` object, but it seems like you need to rethink your logic a bit.

Fortunately, angular has the async pipe which can be used with *ngIf as such:

```js
<div *ngIf="(getPerson(personId) | async) as person">
```

This pipe takes in an observable and "resolves" it to the person object in the html template. It also only renders what's inside of it after this request completes, so you can use properties  of the object freely inside!

Source and some more info:
https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/angular-ngif-async-pipe

Comment: I call my getPerson method in ngOnInit, does this not complete before the html is rendered (this is where I am displaying values of properties on the person object)

Comment: @FeebsMary no, you pass in the observable in there. Angular has this async pipe which in the moment it renders, it subscribes to the observable you passed in and only renders the div itself after request completion!

Comment: I am definitely getting closer to the answer thanks to you, digging deeper on observables here! thank you. first week using angular

Answer (score 0):

Your service method returns an observable, not the person directly.
So if you are inspecting the person object before the observable actually returned an object then it will be undefined.
It's not a bug, it's just how async code works.

In your markup, simply make sure to check if the object is undefined before rendering it :

```
<div *ngIf="person">...</div>
```

The reason why your POST method will work is because you are probably not actually doing anything with the response. If you were to do something like show a toast notification on POST success for example then the same principles would apply, you would have to observe the POST response and do something on success/error.

Comment: Thank you your explanation helped with my understanding of observables!